# If a <td> contains text “0" then make the <td> display none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, contains

I am trying to make a `td` disappear when it contains text `0` using jQuery. I tried this but it did not work:

```js
$(".detail-parameters tr:contains('0')").css("display", "none");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="detail-parameters">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>some text</th>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>some text</th>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: It works here http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/5751/.

Comment: I placed your code in a snippet where it works absolutely fine (although you're hiding the entire `tr`, not the `td`). Check the console for errors

Comment: @kuri Your code work but if a `td` has `01` or `10` text also hide it.

Comment: thank you guys for fast reply, what if I would like to hide td when it contains "0" only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code work but if a `td` has `01` or `10` in text, the code hide it that isn't correct. So you should check text of element in `.filter()` instead using `:contain()`

```js
$(".detail-parameters tr").filter(function(){
  return $(this).find("td").text() == 0;
}).css("display", "none");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="detail-parameters">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>some text</th>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>some text</th>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>some text</th>
      <td>01</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: it is working, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you are using tr instead of using td try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".detail-parameters td:contains('0')").css("display", "none");
});
```

but your code will hide 10 or 01 too.